# How to pass query string to popup window with javascript in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

How to pass query string to popup window with javascript  in asp.net?

```
window.open("HoCCV.aspx?CSS=" + Request["CSS"].ToString(), "newWindow", "width=450,Height=300,addressbar=no,top=200, left=250");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass like this in button click

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />


protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = "HoCCV.aspx?Id=123&Name=Abc";
    string script = "window.open('" + url + "', 'popup_window', 'width=1024,height=768,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');";
 ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "popUp", script, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Method**

Url string

```
var strURL="yourfilepath?string1="+string1+"&string2="+string2+"&string3=+string3+&string4="+string4
```

Then use `window.open()`

```
  var mywindow = window.open(strURL,'','width=690,height=1000,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,top=10,left=200');
```

**Second Method**

use can use hidden fileds

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="samplehiddenfield" runat="server" Value="hidden value"/>
```

**onclick**

```
onclick="window.open('filepath'+passValue(),'FeedbackWindow','width=960,height=640,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=yes')"
```

Then **Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function passValue() {
        var hidden_value = '?' + document.getElementById("<%= samplehiddenfield.ClientID %>").value;
        return hidden_value;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @boshkashh how ? using mycode or did you find any other way ?

Comment: @boshkashh  then you can mark it as right answer .in future somebody can refer it

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function OpenPopUp() {

            var input = '<%= Request.QueryString["CSS"].ToString() %>';
            window.open("HoCCV.aspx?CSS=" + input, "newWindow", "width=450,Height=300,addressbar=no,top=200, left=250");
        }

    </script>

<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit" runat="server"  OnClientClick="OpenPopUp();" />
```

Comment: Why did you post two answers? if you have any change then edit answer and apply the changes

Comment: this function the best one .